# Import DynamoDB Tables into terraform with configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws

I have around 50 dynamodb tables that I want to terraform. The process that I have found so far includes setting up a resource, then running terraform import, and then running terraform plan to see what changes I need to make to my resource config so that there are no changes made. Is there a simpler way to export each dynamodb table as a terraform resource?

Comment: As I know the process you found is the one. You can probably script the imports and plan, iterating on the CLI output to do it faster, but the procedure is right.
Some project to generate TF state from live infrastructure exit but i never tried, do a check https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer